# React Native TextField component in external library on focus

Tags: android, react-native

I have a Register Component that has PhoneInput Component from the external library https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-phone-input  The problem is I want to execute some code as soon as TextField inside the PhoneInput is Focused.

While checking the documentation of the library. I saw a property called the textComponent. Can that be used for onFocus of the text field present in PhoneInput Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input'

export default class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {"phone": ""};
        this.countriesList =  [
            {
                "name": "India (भारत)",
                "iso2": "in",
                "dialCode": "91",
                "priority": 0,
                "areaCodes": null
            }];
        this.phoneTextField=null;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('GrandChild did mount.');
        // console.log(this.phoneTextField);
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.phoneTextField);
        console.log("Register Screen");
        return (
            <View style={{borderColor:'red', borderWidth:0, height:'100%' }}>
                <View style={{borderColor:'green', borderWidth:0, height:'20%' }}>
                    <View style={{borderColor:'blue', borderWidth:0, resizeMode:'contain', width:'50%', height:'100%'}}>
                        <Image
                            style={{width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                            source={ require("../assets/logo.png") }
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{borderColor:'green', borderWidth:0, height:'40%', marginLeft:'1%', marginTop:'5%' }}>
                    <View style={{borderColor:'blue', borderWidth:0, resizeMode:'contain', width:'100%', height:'100%'}}>
                        <Image
                            style={{width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                            source={ require("../assets/welcomescreen.jpg") }
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{ margin : '7%'}}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold' }}>Save your time</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize:14, color:'grey', paddingTop:'5%' }}>Please Enter your mobile number to proceed</Text>
                    <PhoneInput ref={ref => {
                            this.phoneTextField = ref;
                    }}
                                style={{paddingTop:'10%'}}
                                countriesList={this.countriesList}
                                initialCountry='in'
                                onChangePhoneNumber={(phone)=>{
                                    console.log(phone);
                                }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>


        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

My App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Register from "./screens/Register";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("hello bros");
    return (
      <Register/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that library, however, textComponent accepts a function so you should be able to do this

```
textComponent={
  ()=>{
  return(<TextInput 
  ....some props here 
  onFocus={()=>console.log('focused')})
  }}
```